# with resource delta object, identify file delete or file create

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am using Resource Change Listener to track the changes done to my project. This listener is invoked if I delete, or create or save any changes to a file, in the project. I have the ResourceDelta object. With this, how can I find if the file is being created or is going to be deleted.
Below is my code:

In the activator class of my plugin I have:

```
IResourceChangeListener     listener    = new MyResourceChangeListener();
this.workspace.addResourceChangeListener(this.listener);
```

In the MyResourceChangeListener class I have:

```
System.out.println(event.getBuildKind());
System.out.println(event.getSource());
System.out.println(event.getType());
if (event.getType() == IResourceChangeEvent.POST_CHANGE) {
    System.out.println("this is post change event");
    final IResourceDelta delta = event.getDelta();

System.out.println(delta.getFlags());
System.out.println(delta.getKind());
System.out.println(delta.getFlags());

if (delta.getKind() == IResourceDelta.ADDED) {
    System.out.println("this is ADD event");
}

if (delta.getKind() == IResourceDelta.CHANGED) {
    System.out.println("this is CHANGED event");
}

if ((delta.getFlags() & IResourceDelta.CONTENT) == 0) {
        System.out.println("this is CONTENT event");
}
}
```

Output is always as below, either i create a class, delete a class, or make changes and save a class :

```
0
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace@5f9f1f42
1
this is post change event
0
4
0
this is CHANGED event
this is CONTENT event
```

How can I differentiate between save, delete or create events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the bitmap returned by `IResourceChangeEvent.getType()` for PRE_DELETE bit. Register the listener specifically for that event type with `IWorkspace.addResourceChangeListener(IResourceChangeListener, int)`

This [article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Resource-deltas/resource-deltas.html) might be useful, too.